# hide only the account section using internal css

Tags: css, magento

visit this  link : http://4.videomergerapp.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovLzQudmlkZW9tZXJnZXJhcHAuY29tLw,,/

and login with email id : kidsdial2@gmail.com and password : kidsdial2

than on left side , you can see  column with "Marketplace " &

"My account", I want to remove the complete "My account" part.

i am trying following code through inspect element,

.block block-account { display : none; } than its  hiding "My account" part

but when i used this in code file, than both "My account" & "Marketplace"

sections are hiding. i want to hide only "My account" part only in that page, not in entire site.

so i have to use internal css.

please help me for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using same css class either add some parent class between these block or remove from xml.

```
<marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> 
<reference name="left"><remove name="customer_account_navigation"/></reference> </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
```

Comment: hi, nice to see you here..... how to remove " my account " part for some pages using xml .i am using this xml in local.xml =>               <marketplace-marketplaceaccount-editprofile>
    <remove name="customer_account_navigation"/>
 </marketplace-marketplaceaccount-editprofile>

Comment: you can check this for teplate path hints : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/?tp=1&code=toy

Comment: now both Marketplace and My account section is hiding

Comment: ok remove the template hint and add class on marketplace menu

Comment: did you enable the cache kindly disable it and refresh it

Comment: finally i added different class and now its working fine. please check this page : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/ there you can see 1)seller profile 2) new products ....etc its in vertical menu, i want to display as like horizontal menu : http://videomergerapp.com/ please help me for this....

Comment: yo want to add this on top of product?

Comment: i want to change that vertical to horizontal menu and display in top as like this :

http://videomergerapp.com/

Comment: <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> 
<reference name="content"><block type="core/template" before="-" name="abc" template="yourmen/test.phtml"
    /></reference> </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>

Comment: where i need to add the above code before content. is i t in xml file ?

Comment: Remove before  and check

Comment: i tried, but no luck, you can help me here also : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/convert-vertical-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css

Comment: Outside can't reply on question

Comment: May I ask you... Where do you find reference to xml <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>  as for my understanding the question and the visible code online does not contain any of that code. and this could be know only if working on the same project? Thanks

Comment: Simply get from your page url.

Comment: @GibboK , Qaisar Satti helped me lot in other forums, so he mentioned that answer.

Comment: @GibboK  this is magento related question so in magento you can guess the xml from page url.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following CSS, this will hide the "My account".
Generally I suggest you to remove the markup for that section on your template system, as with CSS you can only hide that section.

```
.grid_6.pull_18.col-left.sidebar > div:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Gibbok it worked fine, + 1 from my side.

can you please help me here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/convert-vertical-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css

becuse i can not post one more question in stack overflow until 90 minutes

Comment: now please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650823/convert-vertical-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css

Comment: please help me here :  please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650823/convert-vertical-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css?noredirect=1#comment55075519_33650823